# php5-imagick "no decode delegate" error

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a PSD to a PNG file using PHP on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine.

But I am getting this error:

> "`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format "Abstract origami speech bubble.psd" @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544' in....`"

Here is '`convert -version`' output:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.0-0 Q16 x86_64 2014-12-14 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2014 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: DPC OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr \
                      lzma openexr png tiff x xml zlib
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read or write PSD files, your ImageMagick needs a builtin module called PSD. On my system this is provided by the file `psd.so`:

```
 kp@mbp:>  cd /opt/local/lib/ImageMagick-6.9.0/modules-Q16/coders

 kp@mbp:>  ls -l psd.so
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  59260 Dec  6 04:11 psd.so
```

You should run this command to see if you have support for PSD files:

```
convert -list format | grep -E '(PSD|Modul|----)'
```

For me it returns these lines:

```
   Format  Module    Mode  Description
-----------------------------------------------------------------
      PSB* PSD       rw+   Adobe Large Document Format
      PSD* PSD       rw+   Adobe Photoshop bitmap
```

If you do not have the PSD module installed, you cannot read or write PSD files...

Comment: how did you install PSD module ?

Comment: How ***I*** did it will not help you, since you are on Ubuntu... According to **[this file list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/utopic/i386/libmagickcore5/filelist)**, this delegate coder ***is*** available for Ubuntu!